# Computer restarts when booting Parrot OS

Tags: system-installation, parrotsec

I have an old Laptop (Samsung R610, 4Gb RAM, Core 2 Duo, SSD 275GB).

I chose Parrot Security OS, to try the features they offer.

Installed the 64b version, and chose at first the default options as I suck at partitioning. I then tried multiple options (manual, encrypted, not encrypted, etc.).
Installation went well, but when I start, the GRUB screen loads, and whatever option I choose, OS starts booting, and after the first 2 lines (see below), PC restarts.

Starting lines (translation from french may not be right):

- Linux Loading 4.180-Parrot8-AMD64
- Initial Disk Loading

The computer may as well restart on loading the installation program.

I run the installation program on an 4Go USB key, from the original ISO found on the official Parrot OS site. I used Rufus 3.3 to load the ISO on the key, using the two ways (ISO and DD).

I tried to install another distribution (Zorin OS 12.4) to make a "sample test", but it won't even load the installer.

Would it be a hardware problem (Processor or DDR2 non-compatibility) ?

Comment: Are you working with computer security and penetration testing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: No, please don’t use the Kali dupe for Parrot...

Comment: @Nasir @ Stephen Not at all. I wanted to test it cause it came with "dev tools" and Wine support. Then, when it failed I tried the Home version, thinking it would better suit my needs anyway. I get the exact same problem. Isaac, well, not exactly but I get your point : it fails because I don't use it for what it stands for. Is the Home version based on Kali too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to complete Zorin installation, I found I can't install X64 OS.

Though I sounds obvious for me that the Centrino 2 platform should support 64b versions of OS, it seems not.

My problem with Parrot Home Version most probably came from that.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not going to work with computer security and penetration testing, it's better that you go with a distribution like Debian, Ubuntu, or Mint as Parrot is based off of Debian as are the other two. Those distros are better for a general-purpose workstation as they are much more intuitive for someone who isn't an expert, have more features and packages available, and will function better for regular use. You can install both Wine and the dev tools into any of those other distros.

Parrot isn't meant to be used for such a thing, is more difficult to actually install, and is meant for those who already have an advanced knowledge of Linux and plan to do penetration testing which is also true of Kali Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I totally get the fact that I should not use something for what it's not intended for. I'll forget Parrot then. But why did they make a Home version ?
The problem I showed in the description is I can't install Zorin OS either (installer won't even load), isn't it supposed to be aiming to a larger panel of users ?

Comment: I guess, Zorin installation is out of the scope of this issue. I'll try existing solution before bothering you guys with a problem that could not be related to Parrot.
Thanks for the help :)